# C# - Finding all permutations of the letters in a string with some letters repeated

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, permutation

I am having problems calculating permutations for strings containing multiple instances of a letter (e.g. "HRWSOROE" where 'O' and 'R' are in the string twice.  The algorithm I am using

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return PermutationsImpl(source, Enumerable.Empty<T>());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PermutationsImpl<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> prefix)
    {
        if (!source.Any()) yield return prefix;
        foreach (var permutation in source.SelectMany(x => PermutationsImpl(source.Except(Yield(x)), prefix.Union(Yield(x)))))
            yield return permutation;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T element)
    {
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

Seems to work, but ignores duplicate letters - so instead of calculating permutations on "HRWSOROE" the permutations are being calculated on "HRWSOE".  If someone would be kind enough to review what I have and let me know what they think, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Aaaah... Someones writing a Wordfeud "cheater"... ;)

Comment: With those letters, you can just play HORSEROW for 85 points.

Comment: Yeah, guilty as charged.  Would be rather cool to incorporate this into a neat mobile app.

Comment: @AndyEvans, if you break the dynyx pastebin code into more variables, and use the debugger, [you'll see the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532506/c-finding-all-permutations-of-the-letters-in-a-string-with-some-letters-repeat/7532712#7532712).

Comment: Glancing at the code I'd say your problem is source.Except(Yield(x)) which itself works as Distinct(). But do I have a solution? Hey man... It's friday evening... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be the source.Except(Yield(x)) part in the LINQ line in PermutationsImpl().

It's comparing and removing all the values in the source which match the values in 'x'.